# Immutable installed but still shows not defined

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I did the following to install immutablejs with no errors after install:

```
npm install immutable
```

Then created a local file named implementing_immutablejs.js with the following contents.

```
const { Map } = require('immutable');


const map = Immutable.Map();
console.log(map);
```

When I try to run the file like this

```
node implementing_immutablejs.js
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/larry/Desktop/ImmutableJS/implementing_immutablejs.js:11
const map = Immutable.Map();
            ^

ReferenceError: Immutable is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/larry/Desktop/ImmutableJS/implementing_immutablejs.js:11:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need `Immutable`  you already importing its `Map`. Simply run this

```
const { Map } = require('immutable');


const map = Map();
console.log(map);
```

If you want like first one:

```
const Immutable = require('immutable');
    
    
    const map = Immutable.Map();
    console.log(map);
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham. I did it that way following the docs. But simply running how you suggested is what I should have done.

Comment: Great If you want to play with like first one. Updated my code